# Convert two timestamps to time elapses in Python

Tags: python, string, time, string-conversion

I'm trying to get the time elapsed between two string timestamps in my Python code.
Example:

```
Time Started: "2022-01-07 14:30"
Time Ended: "2022-01-07 15:45"
```

I want the answer to return as an int in number of minutes.
So, in this example it would be 75 since that is the number of minutes elapsed between the starting and ending timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have tried anything. Start with this:

1. Call [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert to datetime objects
2. Subtract the objects to get a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)
3. Divide [timedelta.total_seconds()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) by sixty to get the number of minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
class Convert:
    def main(start,end):
        dt1=datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')
        dt2=datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')
        time1=str(dt1.time()).split(":")
        time2=str(dt2.time()).split(":")
        for i in range(0,len(time1)):
            time1[i]=int(time1[i])
        for j in range(0,len(time2)):
            time2[j]=int(time2[j])
        print(time1)
        hour_to_min1=time1[0]*60+time1[1]+time1[2]
        hour_to_min2=time2[0]*60+time2[1]+time2[2]
        print(hour_to_min1)
        print(hour_to_min2)
        total_time_taken=hour_to_min2-hour_to_min1
        print(f"The total time taken is {total_time_taken} minutes")

start=str(input("Enter datetime in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"))
end=str(input("Enter datetime in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"))

(Convert.main(start,end))
```

This was too simple....:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).